# Forms Authentication working locally but not on Web server

Tags: asp.net, iis

On my local, I have the following settings, which is working fine when run locally.

Web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
     <authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>
</system.web>

<location path="ABCD/ASPX/UserPDF">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

What the above code does is that it has some PDFs saved inside the folder with path "ABCD/ASPX/UserPDF" and when accessed it denies the access to that PDFs.

Below is the screenshot of the error I get when accessed those PDFs.(which is working fine I guess, not allowing access to PDFs)

[image]

Now, I have deployed same web.config settings on my Web server and tried to access the PDFs and I am able to access the PDFs without any restriction.
Is there any IIS settings I am missing, if yes then please help.

NOTE : I am using IIS Version 10.0.14393.0

Comment: "Below is the screenshot of the error I get when accessed those PDFs.(which is working fine I guess, not allowing access to PDFs)". Nope. That's completely wrong. You should solve that first.

Comment: How did you get authorization rule return 404 instead of 401 error?To allow form authentication, you have to disable anonymous authentication and only make it enabled for your Login URL.Then enable form authentication in top site level. Otherwise, the form authentication would not work and your website would be accessed unlimited.